# What is the difference between "Weekly Supply Estimates" and "Weekly U.S. Field Production of Crude Oil"

Tags: supply-and-demand, data, oil

This may sound very redundant and simple to some, but what is the actual difference between the reported Crude Oil Domestic Production "`Weekly Supply Estimates`" [data](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_sum_sndw_a_epc0_fpf_mbblpd_w.htm) and the "`Weekly U.S. Field Production of Crude Oil`" [data](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WCRFPUS2&f=W)?

Is the Weekly Supply Estimates is a data derivative of the Weekly [Imports](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WCRIMUS2&f=W)/[Exports](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WCREXUS2&f=W)/[Production](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WCRFPUS2&f=W)? Or is the Supply is the Finished Goods (e.g., actual gasoline) and not Crude Oil itself?

[image]
[image]
[image]